# Change Color of AppBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-styles

I am trying to understand, what is the difference between `Toolbar`, `Appbar`, `ActionBar`. And i am trying to change the color of my AppBar or whatever it is to red.

Someone mention try changing the theme. I tried but don't know the difference and i am also new to android programming. So if you could help me out. Here is the styles.xml file code

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTextTitle</item>

</style>

<style name="MyTextTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

[image: Look in the image. I want to change the color of MoboLock text.]

I hope you understand what i am trying to say. And forgive me for my ignorance as i am keen to learn it so can't just wait.

Comment: Tool bar is a replacement for actionbar ,Tool bar is more customizable

Comment: @Redman  And what is appbar? And how can I change the text color of toolbar? If you could help me.

Comment: The app bar, formerly known as the action bar in Android, is a special kind of toolbar that’s used for branding, navigation, search, and actions.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html  , see this appbar is also known as action bar

Comment: how can I change the text color of toolbar? --> while designing toolbar when you keep textview in it , make its textcolor to what ever colour you want

Comment: @Mahrukh Raza did you get an idea and fixed your error s?

Comment: Liked the note, "whatever it is" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html)

> The **app bar**, also known as the action bar, is one of the most
>   important design elements in your app's activities....

and from [material.io](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)

> The **app bar**, formerly known as the action bar in Android, is a special
>   kind of toolbar that’s used for branding, navigation, search, and
>   actions

again from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html)

> A **Toolbar** is a generalization of action bars for use within
>   application layouts. While an action bar is traditionally part of an
>   Activity's opaque window decor controlled by the framework, a Toolbar
>   may be placed at **any arbitrary level** of nesting within a view
>   hierarchy. An application may choose to designate a Toolbar as the
>   action bar for an Activity using the `setActionBar()` method.

If this is not clear you need to clear theese two words first **generalization** vs **specialization** according to our topic `Toolbar` supports a *more* focused feature set than `ActionBar`.

Further from [blog.xamarin.com](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/)

> You can think of the **Toolbar** as the Action Bar’s **bigger** sibling that
>   has grown up and is free to roam around the house by itself.

**Let's clear things above mentioned**

I have made a `navigationDrawerActivity` which i can easily create and did some change for you to clear the mess.

I change color of the `AppBarLayout` 
Removed the toolbar from it's position and set in inside `content_main.xml` because if both stand in the same spot you might not get the idea!

[image]

See you can place it anywhere!

If you want to change the color of `AppBarLayout` add this inside it `android:background="@color/your_color"`

Now if you read above quotes you know which one is `toolbar`

This is my `action_bar_main.xml` (i removed `toolbar` from this and set it inside `content_main.xm`l)

---

Now you asked to change the text color of `toolbar`

If you want you can set your own design layout for that then `include` it.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_inflater" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

If you only want to change the background color change it's `background`

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

See i have inflated a layout as i need.There you can add your views as your preference.

or if you want to change the text in tool bar using code

```
 CharSequence title = "Your App Name";
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(title);
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);
```

or even you can do it by changing the textcolor of it's theme. Read [www.murrayc.com](https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655908/setting-android-toolbar-background-and-text-colors-in-android-studio-1-4-1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288402/how-to-set-custom-actionbar-color-style?noredirect=1&lq=1) so posts

---

**Side Note : Setting Up the App Bar**

If you go the [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html) it says,

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), all activities that use the
>   default theme have an ActionBar as an app bar. However, app bar
>   features have gradually been added to the native ActionBar over
>   various Android releases. As a result, the native ActionBar behaves
>   **differently** depending on what version of the Android system a device
>   may be using. By contrast, the most recent features are added to the
>   support library's version of Toolbar, and they are available on any
>   device that can use the support library.
>
> For this reason, you **should use** the support library's Toolbar class to
>   implement your activities' app bars. Using the support library's
>   toolbar helps ensure that your app will have consistent behavior
>   across the **widest range** of devices. For example, the Toolbar widget
>   provides a material design experience on devices running Android 2.1
>   (API level 7) or later, but the native action bar doesn't support
>   material design unless the device is running Android 5.0 (API level
>   21) or later

Below above description there is a main sub topic **Add a Toolbar to an Activity** which strongly force you to use tool bar by [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html)

So Bye bye `App Bar` say Hi to `Toolbar`

Comment: Thank you brother.

Comment: @Mahrukh Raza you are welcome you can up vote if it helps you ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this in your app theme :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

[image]

hope his helps you out

Answer (score 0):

Try This,`<color name="colorPrimary">#0b0b0c</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#0b0b0c</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
Whatever color to change in hexadecimal code.then see ur app changes made it.`

Answer (score 0):

You can change color using `setBackgroundColor` method of Appbar.
if you have tab bar in that you can set `OnTabSelectedListener` like this

```
tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        }

        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
            when(tab.position){
                0->app_bar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))
                1->app_bar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4286f4"))
                2->app_bar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2ff00"))
            }
        }

    } )
```