# Change the text color of the toolbar overview

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I cannot find how to change the text color of the overview toolbar on Android.. :

[image: On Navigation menu click]

I tried this one :

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

<style name="AppBlankTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBlankTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I want to change the color of the title ("Sharezone") and the close button of the overview toolbar to white.

Thanks.

------------------------- EDIT -------------------------------------------

After a lot of failed solutions, here's my entire code :

style.xml

```
<style name="AppBlankTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBlankTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/grey_300</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </activity>
</application>
```

And here's the toolbar I use in Activity :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_300"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: check out this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655908/setting-android-toolbar-background-and-text-colors-in-android-studio-1-4-1

Comment: check if you apply "AppTheme" and not "AppBlankTheme" to the layout of "Sharezone".

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `Theme`.which you have set in your style 
`style name="AppBlankTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

please use this Theme

`style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Now your App's dark theme will be removed

Comment: Please let me know if you still have any issue @user3185672

Comment: Still not working.. I edit the post with others elements of the code. Thanks anyways for your answer @ghanshyam-sharma

Answer (score 0):

**#.** Seems your `themes` are OK. In `AndroidManifest.xml` file, apply `AppTheme` to your desired `Activity`.

**`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

**#.** If you are using `Toolbar` in your layout `XML`, then you can change its `title` color programmatically:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

**UPDATE:**

As per your updated question, seems you are using custom `Toolbar`. To change title `"Sharezone"` color, you have to change the `background` color of `TextView` (`toolbar_app_name`).

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by XML, if your activity is called MainActivity go to the res/layout/activity_main, go to design and press/select the action bar, then to properties on the right and select titleTextColor and change tot he required colour.

[image: select title bar]

Choose colour here:
[image: Choose colour]